# plugin from http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/ is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me to sort out my issue.

i got a plugin from http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/  and when i try to open a popup window (iframe) in **IE8** it is **not working** but **Firefox ,chrome ,safari and IE9** are **working properly**.
The error says that

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'constructor': object is null or undefined 
jquery-impromptu.3.2.min.js, line 37 character 9
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried contacting the makers of the plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating your jquery version

they are using jquery v1.7.1 may be that can help you and also they are using impromptu.4.0.min.js please upgrade both files and then try

make sure you have included all the required js file try viewing source code of their site

you can download jquery v1.7.1 from [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/)

all the best